# WebGL - When should I call bindBuffer and vertexAttribPointer?

Tags: performance, optimization, webgl, vertex-buffer

This question is specific to WebGL and assumes VAOs are not available.

I'm trying to make some little improvements to a 3D engine by limiting the number of low-level state changes. But it turns out I'm a bit confused about the proper way to use `bindBuffer` and `vertexAttribPointer`.

Let's say I want to draw 2 objects:

- The first object make use of two buffers *A* and *C* with an element buffer *E* ;
- the second object uses buffers *B* and *C* with the same element buffer *E*.

Buffers *A* and *B* use the same layout and are both referenced by location 0 while *C* is referenced by location 1.

Initially, `ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING` points to null while `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING` points to *E*.

The redundancy checker outputs the following with (*A*, *B*, *C*, *E*) = (3, 6, 5, 2):

[image: WebGL Inspector trace]

Which means that:

1. `bindBuffer(ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, [Buffer 2])` is unnecessary
2. `vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, FLOAT, false, 0, 0)` could've been avoided

Since WebGL can **directly** read `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING` to know where indices are stored, 1. makes sense to me.

However, 2. implies that the buffer layout is stored *inside* the VBO, which is wrong because Buffer *A* and *B* are not seen as redundant on lines 15 and 30. (Several frames were rendered already, so they should have kept their state)

I think I'm confused about how `drawElements` know **what buffer to use** and **where/when buffer layouts are stored**.

What is the optimal use of `bindBuffer` and `vertexAttribPointer` for this example case and why?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I find out by simply looking at the source of the [redundancy checker](https://github.com/benvanik/WebGL-Inspector/blob/c5f961dba261cbd94d9b3ff3ddbaf8b7d3bf5ef9/core/replay/RedundancyChecker.js#L393).

There are 2 important things to know :

- Buffer layouts are bound **per location** and not per VBO.
- `vertexAttribPointer` will also **assign the current buffer** to the given location

Internally, WebGL retains 6 parameters per location :

```
VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_SIZE_X
VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_TYPE_X
VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_NORMALIZED_X
VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_STRIDE_X
VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_POINTER_X
VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_X
```

Here's what `vertexAttribPointer` does :

```
function vertexAttribPointer(indx, size, type, normalized, stride, offset) {
    this.stateCache["VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_SIZE_" + indx] = size;
    this.stateCache["VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_TYPE_" + indx] = type;
    this.stateCache["VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_NORMALIZED_" + indx] = normalized;
    this.stateCache["VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_STRIDE_" + indx] = stride;
    this.stateCache["VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_POINTER_" + indx] = offset;
    this.stateCache["VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_" + indx] = this.stateCache["ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING"];
}
```

Finally, WebGL Inspector was true! State changes line 15 and 30 are necessary because the `VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING_0` is changing.

Here's the optimal trace :

```
bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, A)
vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
drawElements(TRIANGLES, 768, UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0)
bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, B)
vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
drawElements(TRIANGLES, 768, UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0)
```

(`bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, C)` is not needed anymore, since we aren't doing anything with it.)